# На происходит вставка(prepend) html из js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть форма, при сабмите которой мне нужно что бы на странице появились введенные данные.
На странице они выводятся так: Есть один блок `wrap`, в котором содержаться комментарии(их может быть много). Тело комментария - это всё, что находиться в `ol`.
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не происходит вставка?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wrap").prepend("<ol class='comments-list'><li class='comment'><div class='activity_rounded'></div><div class='comment-body'><h4 class='text-left'>Name<small class='date-posted'></small></h4><p>Text</p><a href='#leave_comment' class='pull-left reply'>Reply</a><div class='clearfix'></div></div></li></ol>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <ol class="comments-lists">
    <li class="comment">
      <div class="activity_rounded"></div>
      <div class="comment-body">
        <h4 class="text-left">
          <span id="author-name">Name<span><small class="date-posted">Date</small>
                  </h4>
                  <p>Text</p>
                  <a href="#leave_comment" class="pull-left reply">Reply</a>
           <div class="clearfix"></div>
         </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что у вас элемент с классом  `.wrap`, а не с id `#wrap`.

Смотрите внимательно на селектор.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // поиск по классу
  $(".wrap").prepend("<ol class='comments-list'><li class='comment'><div class='activity_rounded'></div><div class='comment-body'><h4 class='text-left'>Name<small class='date-posted'></small></h4><p>Text</p><a href='#leave_comment' class='pull-left reply'>Reply</a><div class='clearfix'></div></div></li></ol>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <ol class="comments-lists">
    <li class="comment">
      <div class="activity_rounded"></div>
      <div class="comment-body">
        <h4 class="text-left">
          <span id="author-name">Name<span><small class="date-posted">Date</small>
                  </h4>
                  <p>Text</p>
                  <a href="#leave_comment" class="pull-left reply">Reply</a>
           <div class="clearfix"></div>
         </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
</div>
```